# I am trying to hide a custom post type category to logged in users with Pre_Get_Posts

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, query, pre-get-posts

I have a custom post type in my theme called portfolio. It's categories are called project-categories. I am trying to exclude a project category for logged in users. I cannot get this to work at all.  I have read through the [pre_get_posts codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) but I am just stuck.  I'm not sure if I am defining the categories for my custom post type or if it would be the same as a normal post category.  When I click on the category to edit it, this is in the browser url bar

`wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=project-type&tag_ID=94&post_type=po‌​rtfolio`

Here is the code I'm trying right now.

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $taxquery = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'project-type',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => array( 94 ),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );

        $query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you have few mistakes in there.

1. `field` can be `term_id` or `slug`, but not `id`.
2. `tax_query` should be array of arrays and not an array.

So here is fixed code:

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $taxquery = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'project-type',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => array( 94 ),
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            ),
        );

        $query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

It's not tested, but I'm pretty sure it should work just fine.

Comment: Hey Krzysiek, thanks for the response.  I tried the code and it's still not hiding the category. I have tried just about everything I can think of.  I think it's something going on with the theme that is stopping it from working. If I send you the wordpress zip and sql of a fresh install with a simple portfolio would you be able to take a look at it?

Comment: Hmm, are you sure that this theme is using native wp_query? Maybe it's creating its own query in this template.

Comment: no I'm not sure, I've contacted support but their responses are pretty slow. Would this be it? I found it in the functions.php `$portfolio = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio' );
$the_query = new WP_Query($portfolio);`